# how do I put middleware on lumen route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I need to put middleware on route in lumen project. So far I've been working with Laravel but now I'm in a project that is  using lumen.

Documentation here: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

gives us

```
$app->get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    //
}]);
```

while my route look like this

```
$app->get('/', 'UsersController@all');
```

I've tried this:

```
$app->get('/', ['middleware' => 'haspermission:backend-users-list'], 'UsersController@all');
```

but it does not work.

What is the right way to do it if I am not using a function directly in route to return some data?

Comment: what is the keyword `haspermission` here? is it laravel inbuilt like `can:` for Gate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this solution [github](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/311)

```
$app->get('/', ['middleware' => 'haspermission:backend-users-list', 'uses' => 'UsersController@all']);
```